# I'm trying to make an automated BannedUser message and it says I'm missing a parameter

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

Error: No overload for 'UserBanned' matches delegate 'Func'

I know that my banned user message is missing a parameter, and I know I have to put something in the brackets for this parameter, but I'm utterly clueless as to what exactly I'm supposed to put. I've looked for a good hour or two and maybe the answer was thrown in my face but I didn't know it, but I still don't know what to do with it. I think I'm supposed to add a variable in the brackets, but I'm not exactly sure what.

```
public async Task RunBotAsync()
    {
        _client = new DiscordSocketClient(new DiscordSocketConfig
        {
            LogLevel = LogSeverity.Verbose
        });
        _commands = new CommandService();
        _services = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton(_client)
            .AddSingleton(_commands)
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        string botToken = "Token";

        //event subscriptions
        _client.Log += Log;
        _client.UserJoined += UserJoined;
        _client.UserLeft += UserLeft;
        _client.UserBanned += UserBanned; //<- Error Line

        await RegisterCommandsAsync();

        await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, botToken);

        await _client.StartAsync();

        await Task.Delay(-1);
    }

    private async Task UserBanned(SocketGuildUser user, IGuild bloop)
    {
        var guild = user.Guild;
        var announcements = _client.GetChannel(390418472783577088) as SocketTextChannel;
        await announcements.SendMessageAsync($"{user.Mention} was banned from the server.");
    }
```

Comment: Why is the exact error message not included in your post? And why haven't you identified which line is causing it? You have those details right on the screen in front of you. They would be useful to us as well.

Comment: Is that better?

Answer (score 0):

from the line:

```
_client.UserBanned += UserBanned;
```

the referenced function should be something like the following.

```
async Task UserBanned(SocketUser user, SocketGuild bloop)
{
    var guild = user.Guild;
    var announcements = _client.GetChannel(390418472783577088) as SocketTextChannel;
    await announcements.SendMessageAsync($"{user.Mention} was banned from the server.");
}
```

[Discord.WebSocket.BaseSocketClient.UserBanned](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.WebSocket.BaseSocketClient.html#Discord_WebSocket_BaseSocketClient_UserBanned)

It looked like you needed a SocketGuild arg instead of a IGuild Interface.

Comment: I changed IGuild to SocketGuild but it's still giving me the same error. Is something supposed to go in the brackets in correlation with it?

Comment: That's exactly what my code looks like, but I'm still getting the same error.